# Migration history inaccurate after modifying a generated code first migration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Let's say I have a code first migration that gets generated which looks like this:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Genders",
    c => new
        {
            ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
            Name = c.String(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Ratings",
    c => new
        {
            Value = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Value);

AddColumn("dbo.Reviews", "RatingValue", c => c.Int());
AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "GenderID", c => c.Int());
CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "GenderID");
CreateIndex("dbo.Reviews", "RatingValue");
AddForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "GenderID", "dbo.Genders", "ID");
AddForeignKey("dbo.Reviews", "RatingValue", "dbo.Ratings", "Value");
```

I'm creating 2 tables and adding foreign keys from other tables to these new tables. Simple stuff. Now, let's say that after I use `Add-Migration` to generate this migration, I remove the code that adds the foreign keys to get this:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Genders",
    c => new
        {
            ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
            Name = c.String(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Ratings",
    c => new
        {
            Value = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Value);
```

When I run this through `Update-Database`, it works fine, but then I notice that the migration history keeps the original generated script instead of my edited script. I can confirm this by doing `Add-Migration` again and seeing that the generated migration is empty.

Why is this? Am I going about this wrong? What if I made a bunch of model changes, but I want to break up the migration into separate chunks? How can I do that?

Comment: Did you delete the MigrationHistory table?

Comment: No, but should I have to? Is it expected to be unable to manually edit the migration file?

Comment: If you edit a migration file for an already applied migration it will not update the database with your changes - it uses the migration name and the matching row in MigrationHistory to determine if a migration should be run.

Comment: @eoghank, maybe I misunderstand `Add-Migration`. Does that command do more than simply generate the migration script? Does it actually *apply* that script? I thought that was what `Update-Database` did. Please clarify.

Comment: You are coorect, Update-Database will apply the change but you mentioned in your question that you'd run Update-Database. If you want to re-run a migration you can delete the migration history table or rollback to a previous migration also using update-database